# Error en PostgreSQL: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «blog»

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentando crear una serie de tablas para la base pero salta ese error, he intentado muchas cosas e incluso leido respuestas al mismo tipo de error en otras paginas pero no doy con la solución.
Les dejo solo una parte del codigo porque no me deja ponerlo completamente:

```
CREATE TABLE pagina (
    idpagina SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    texto VARCHAR(480),
    nombreusuario VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (nombreusuario)
    REFERENCES usuario(nombreusuario)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE blog (
    idblog INT,
    idpagina INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idblog,idpagina),
    FOREIGN KEY (idpagina)
    REFERENCES pagina(idpagina)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE

);

CREATE TABLE post(
    idpost INT,
    texto VARCHAR(480),
    fecha DATE,
    hora TIME,
    idblog INT,
    idfoto INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idpost, idblog),
    FOREIGN KEY (idblog)
        REFERENCES blog (idblog)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (idfoto)
        REFERENCES foto(idfoto)
        ON UPDATE SET NULL
        ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE comentapost (
    nombreusuario VARCHAR(30),
    idpost INT,
    fecha DATE,
    hora TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (nombreusuario, idpost),
    FOREIGN KEY (nombreusuario)
        REFERENCES usuario (nombreusuario)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (idpost)
        REFERENCES post (idpost)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE comentariopost (
    comentario VARCHAR(480),
    nombreusuario VARCHAR(30),
    idpost INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (comentario, nombreusuario, idpost),
    FOREIGN KEY (nombreusuario)
        REFERENCES usuario(nombreusuario)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (idpost)
        REFERENCES post (idpost)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Este es exactamente el error que da:
ERROR:  no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «blog»
SQL state: 42830

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Una Llave foránea es una proyección de una llave primaria o de cualquier conjunto que garantice unicidad (un index unique). Por lo tanto, no es válido que uses sólo una parte de la PK compuesta en la tabla `blog` para crear una FK en la tabla `post`.

Tienes

```
 FOREIGN KEY (idblog)
        REFERENCES blog (idblog)
```

Pero la PK en blog es compuesta y tiene los dos campos `idblog, idpagina`. El campo idblog, por sí sólo, no tiene un índice que garantice unicidad de los valores.

Así pues, la solución es una de estas:

- que ajustes las FK para que usen los campos de la PK en la tabla correspondiente. La FK con references a todos los campos en la PK de `blog`.
- Que le añadas un constraint UNIQUE a la columna que quieres referenciar.
- O que la PK en blog no sea compuesta y sólo use el id, por ejemplo.

Ya depende de tu definición del negocio y cómo expresar eso en el modelo de datos.

Comment: Es posible establecer la clave foranea con ambos atributos que son clave primaria de la otra tabla?

Comment: @ElCh8vezDel8 DEBES establecerla con todos los campos de la clave primaria.

Comment: podrias mostrarme como quedaria la tabla post ? lo intente pero no consigo que funcione. Gracias!

Comment: No coincido en que sea estrictamente "una proyección de una clave primaria". Una clave foránea es aplicable a cualquier campo/s que cumplan una restricción de unicidad, no explícitamente una clave primaria.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo gracias por la corrección, tienes razón, esa frase es misleading

Comment: Al formar la clave foranea esta vez con ambos campos que son PK en blog no me reconoce idpagina como atributo en dicha tabla.  ERROR:  no existe la columna «idpagina» referida en la llave foránea