# No puedo crear una tabla con clave foránea de una tabla heredada

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy intentando crear la siguiente tabla que tendrá diversas claves foráneas. Pero en el momento de intentar ejecutar la consulta, me sale el siguiente error "no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «aules_hardware» SQL state: 42830"

La consulta que estoy intentando realizar es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE alumnes(
nom VARCHAR(50),
primercognom VARCHAR(50),
segoncognom VARCHAR(50),
email VARCHAR(50),
idalumne INT,
edat INT,
id_cicle INT,
idclase INT,
idaulainfo INT,
idprofessorsuperior INT,
aficcions TEXT ARRAY,
PRIMARY KEY (idalumne),
FOREIGN KEY (id_cicle) REFERENCES cicles(id_cicle),
FOREIGN KEY (idclase) REFERENCES clases(id_aula),
FOREIGN KEY (idaulainfo) REFERENCES aules_hardware(id_aula), /* Esto da error */
)
```

Las tablas que da error fue creada de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE TABLE clases(
id_aula INT,
nomaula VARCHAR(50),
numpersones INT,
metres_quadrats INT
PRIMARY KEY (id_aula)
)

CREATE TABLE aules_hardware(
model_ordinadors TEXT ARRAY,
num_ordinadors INT
)INHERITS (clases)
```

El gestor de bases de datos que utilizo es PostgreSQL

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en PostgreSQL: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «blog»](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404584/error-en-postgresql-no-hay-restricci%c3%b3n-unique-que-coincida-con-las-columnas-dad)